# NPM install global trying to move bin before postinstall

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I have a npm module with a `bin` specified in `package.json`, the bin is a file compiled with babel, and is not present in the package when the package is installed. I am using the `postinstall` script to run `babel` and generate the build files which `main` and `bin` point to. When I install globally, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/treggi/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/my-module-reggi/lib/functionality/bin.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/treggi/.nvm/versions/node/v9.2.0/lib/node_modules/my-module-reggi/lib/functionality/bin.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/treggi/.npm/_logs/2018-02-27T21_23_05_056Z-debug.log
➜  Desktop code /Users/treggi/.npm/_logs/2018-02-27T21_23_05_056Z-debug.log
```

How can I use a javascript file transpiled with babel as a bin?

Comment: Could you transpile it pre-publish? That way it would be available already and wouldn't have to be transpiled when a user installs.

Comment: I am using babel-env current to transpile based on the current version of node. The idea being I want to optimize the code run based on native node features.